# Which has more importance?

Tags: meaning

From [Election night commentary: women rule](https://www.texasmonthly.com/burka-blog/election-night-commentary-women-rule/)

> But I’d argue that she won as much because she’s a woman as **anything**
> **else**.

Does 'anything else' represent other circumstances, e.g. she is rich?

So,

> But I’d argue that she won as much because she’s a woman as [she won]
> because she is rich.

Without more context, can we know ***she’s a woman*** has more importance than ***she’s rich***?

Comment: 'Anything else' presumably refers to the candidate's political policies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*as much as* is an idiom](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20much%20as)

> as much as

> idiom (1)
> 1
> —used to say that two things are **equal** in amount or degree [emphasis added]

> But I’d argue that she won as much because she’s a woman as anything else.

Yes, 'anything else' can represent other circumstances, as you have stated.

In

> But I’d argue that she won as much [**because she’s a woman**] as [**because she is rich**].

the second *she won* should be deleted, as I have done, to achieve parallelism.

The example says *that she’s a woman* and *that she’s rich* are **equal in degree** in importance.

It does not say the first factor is more important than the second.

Comment: Just noting the fact that the meaning of **as much as** is readily discernible from its elements, so the definition of "idiom" that M-W has in mind is a "syntactical, grammatical, or structural form" rather than "having a meaning that cannot be derived from ... its elements".